# Find duplicate in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, algorithm, merge

I have a table that contains duplicate.
The way to identify a duplicate is
 - the key should be in the same group(1,2,3 or 4)
 - the p should be the same
 - P is an id that say this keys are the same
A key could match multiple times in the same group only.

Let's say we have this sample below :

```
key,p,group
1,1,1
33,1,1
5,1,1
5,2,1
4,2,1
4,15,1
8,4,1
10,5,1
15,6,1
21,15,1
78,7,1
79,8,2
80,8,2
81,9,3
82,9,3
85,10,4
90,11,1
91,11,1
73,12,1
```

The output should be :

```
key,p,group
1,999,1
5,999,1
4,999,1
21,999,1
33,999,1
8,4,1
10,5,1
15,6,1
78,7,1
79,111,2
80,111,2
81,666,3
82,666,3
85,10,4
90,222,1
91,222,1
73,12,1
```

1,5,4,21 and 33 have the same value for p(999, this number is just a new id for grouping the duplicate together),
because they are in the same group (group=1) and 1,5 and 33  match (p=1) , 5 and 4 match (p=2) , 4 and  21 match (p=15)

For 90,91 even they are in the group 1, they match only together because they are not link(cross) with the other key in this group.

79 and 80 are in the same group (group=2)

8 keep p = 4 because he does not match with other keys in the group = 1.

and so forth ...
I'm looking for a way to do it in SQL(Oracle) or an algorithm ...

Actually,
it is not working.
If you have this in input :

```
key,p,group
55,9,6
56,10,6
56,11,6
58,9,6
58,11,6
```

The output will be

```
key,p,group
55,9,6
56,9,6
58,9,6
56,10,6
58,10,6
```

or I need :

```
key,p,group
55,9,6
56,9,6
58,9,6
56,9,6
58,9,6
```

Thanks for help

Comment: How do you determine the new group `p` value? Did you just arbitrarily chosen something?

Comment: Yes, the new p, for example 999 is just a random id.I put 999 to explain. But I can say all the duplicate will take one of the existing p.For example 1,5,4,21 and 33 will use 15(the p of 4 and 21).

Comment: May be it's possible if I use the table twice. I join the tables on p. And after I use the column key from the first table and the second in a hierarchical query. The son will be on one side and the parent on the other side. Instead of having 999 I will have the same parent key for all duplicates.

Comment: That way you only solve for chains of length 2, if you expect very long chains in your data, then that is not a very wise solution

Comment: Trying to understand the problem... It seems you are looking to group together rows based on one or more conditions. It seems one condition is that each "group" is a separate entity - there will be no association between rows with different `group` value. Then, within a group, all the rows with the same `p` value are linked together. Then, within a group, if two different `p`-value subgroups have a row with the same key, then the two groups are combined into a single one. Example: 5,1,1 and 5,2,1 means within key=1, the subgroups with p=1 and p=2 will be joined together.

Comment: And then, when all is done, all you want to do is to change the p value so that it is the same for all rows in the final groups? Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Hi - in the original post, you discarded duplicate rows from the output. In the edit (added later) you are keeping the duplicates. I am editing the solution to correct the mistake (I was able to); I am still using select DISTINCT in the final query, but if you must keep the duplicates, it's easy - just remove the word DISTINCT from the outer query (at the bottom of the code).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the problem correctly: view the rows as the nodes of a (non-directed) graph, with edges joining nodes if they have the same p and group values OR the same key and group values. Then find the connected components of this graph, and change the p value so that all nodes in a connected component have the same p value.

If so, this can be done with a hierarchical query (plus all the processing needed before and after it; the main piece is the hierarchical query). In the solution below, I change all the p values in a connected component to the MIN of p values in the group (rather than a random value); if "random values" are desired that can be done too, but it's a different question with a much simpler solution (and may not be needed in the first place).

GROUP is not a good column name since it's a reserved word in Oracle. I changed it to GRP.

```
with
-- begin test data (this is not part of the solution)
     inputs ( key, p, grp ) as (
       select  1,  1, 1 from dual union all
       select 33,  1, 1 from dual union all
       select  5,  1, 1 from dual union all
       select  5,  2, 1 from dual union all
       select  4,  2, 1 from dual union all
       select  4, 15, 1 from dual union all
       select  8,  4, 1 from dual union all
       select 10,  5, 1 from dual union all
       select 15,  6, 1 from dual union all
       select 21, 15, 1 from dual union all
       select 78,  7, 1 from dual union all
       select 79,  8, 2 from dual union all
       select 80,  8, 2 from dual union all
       select 81,  9, 3 from dual union all
       select 82,  9, 3 from dual union all
       select 85, 10, 4 from dual union all
       select 90, 11, 1 from dual union all
       select 91, 11, 1 from dual union all
       select 73, 12, 1 from dual union all
       select 55,  9, 6 from dual union all
       select 56, 10, 6 from dual union all
       select 56, 11, 6 from dual union all
       select 58,  9, 6 from dual union all
       select 58, 11, 6 from dual
     ),
-- end of test data; solution (SQL query) continues below this line
     prep ( grp, parent, child ) as (
       select distinct a.grp, a.p, b.p
       from   inputs a inner join inputs b
                       on a.grp = b.grp and a.key = b.key
     ),
     h ( grp, rt, child ) as (
       select grp, connect_by_root parent, child
       from   prep
       connect by nocycle grp = prior grp and parent = prior child
     )
select distinct i.key, g.new_p as p, i.grp
from   inputs i join (
                       select grp, rt, min(child) as new_p
                       from   h
                       group by grp, rt
                     ) g
                 on g.grp = i.grp and g.rt = i.p
order by grp, p, key   --   optional
;
```

**Output**:

```
       KEY          P        GRP
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          1
         4          1          1
         5          1          1
        21          1          1
        33          1          1
         8          4          1
        10          5          1
        15          6          1
        78          7          1
        90         11          1
        91         11          1
        73         12          1
        79          8          2
        80          8          2
        81          9          3
        82          9          3
        85         10          4
        55          9          6
        56          9          6
        58          9          6

20 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thanks this exactly what I need. Take the min of is a better choice than using a random values.Now I will test with more data to check and test the performance

Comment: Actually, it's not working some case.It will return a wrong result. So may be SQL is not strong enough to handle this

Comment: Do you care to explain that? In what cases does it not work? Also, what does "not work" mean - do you get an error? The wrong result? Does the program crash (run out of memory)? Or what?

Comment: sure,I found a case in my data. I have added the case in the main post.below Actually, it is not working. If you have this in input :

Comment: @Linus - yes, OK, I see your counter example, and I am reproducing the same (incorrect) output on my system. I'll give it some thought to see why this happens; it should be possible to do it in SQL.

Comment: I tired since last time, always the same result.It looks like a dead end.

Comment: @Linus - I understand why what I wrote doesn't work. Thinking about how to overcome it. It should be a "standard problem" - given a non-oriented (non-directed) graph, find the connected components. I'll research it and post a solution (or I will let you know if/when I give up). Good catch!

Comment: no worries, I'm struggling with that since 2 weeks.

Comment: @Linus - I think I got it. Please try again. In the end the query doesn't look that different from the original one, but in reality what it does is, in fact, different. It may take a little longer than the original version, too, but I hope it will still run in reasonable time.

Comment: Thanks, I was not able to re test , now I'm back will try and check

Answer (score 0):

```
select KEY, 
       P, 
       GRP, 
       'group of '||count(*) over (partition by p,grp)||' with p value '||p
from key_table
```

Output:

```
1   1   1   group of 3 with p value 1
33  1   1   group of 3 with p value 1
5   1   1   group of 3 with p value 1
5   2   1   group of 2 with p value 2
4   2   1   group of 2 with p value 2
8   4   1   group of 1 with p value 4
10  5   1   group of 1 with p value 5
15  6   1   group of 1 with p value 6
78  7   1   group of 1 with p value 7
79  8   2   group of 2 with p value 8
80  8   2   group of 2 with p value 8
81  9   3   group of 2 with p value 9
82  9   3   group of 2 with p value 9
85  10  4   group of 1 with p value 10
91  11  1   group of 2 with p value 11
90  11  1   group of 2 with p value 11
73  12  1   group of 1 with p value 12
4   15  1   group of 2 with p value 15
21  15  1   group of 2 with p value 15
```

I am not too keen on random values, however change the output function as you like.

Comment: Thanks but this is not the result I was expecting.
I want to merge the data at the end.
1,5,4,21 and 33 should have the same value for p at the end.
That means that 1,5,4,21 and 33 are duplicate.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question before, it is a whole different thing if we need to link together in a chain the p values to register groups. I will try to come up with something later.

Comment: No worries.I'm here to find a solution.Here it's a sample I could have multiple keys in a group with the same p and multiple cross keys between p.Very tough